# Why AVX dot product slower than native C++ code

Tags: c++, performance, simd, avx

I have the following AVX and Native codes:

```
__forceinline double dotProduct_2(const double* u, const double* v)   
{  
    _mm256_zeroupper();   
    __m256d xy          = _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_load_pd(u), _mm256_load_pd(v));
    __m256d temp        = _mm256_hadd_pd(xy, xy);
    __m128d dotproduct  = _mm_add_pd(_mm256_extractf128_pd(temp, 0), _mm256_extractf128_pd(temp, 1));
    return dotproduct.m128d_f64[0];
}

__forceinline double dotProduct_1(const D3& a, const D3& b)
{
    return a[0] * b[0] + a[1] * b[1] + a[2] * b[2] + a[3] * b[3];
}
```

And respective test scripts:

```
std::cout << res_1 << " " << res_2 << " " << res_3 << '\n';
{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 30); ++i)
    {
        zx_1 += dotProduct_1(aVx[i % 10000], aVx[(i + 1) % 10000]);
    }
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "NAIVE : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << '\n';
}

{
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < (1 << 30); ++i)
    {
        zx_2 += dotProduct_2(&aVx[i % 10000][0], &aVx[(i + 1) % 10000][0]);
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    std::cout << "AVX : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << '\n';
}

std::cout << math::min2(zx_1, zx_2) << " " << zx_1 << " " << zx_2;
```

Well, all of the data are aligned by 32. (D3 with __declspec... and aVx arr with _mm_malloc()..)
And, as i can see, native variant is equal/or faster than AVX variant. I can't understand it's nrmally behaviour ? Because i'm think that AVX is 'super FAST' ... If not, how i can optimize it ? I compile it on MSVC 2015(x64), with arch AVX. Also, my hardwre is intel i7 4750HQ(haswell)

Comment: Post the ASM that MSVC makes from them.  It probably auto-vectorizes with something more efficient than `vhaddpd`.  Ideally it uses FMADDPD into a vector accumulator and saves all the horizontal summing for the end.  If MSVC doesn't optimize away your manually-vectorized shuffles, then it's not going to be fast.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-float-vector-sum-on-x86 for more about why `hadd` is the wrong shuffle.

Comment: Not to mention that you can't inquire into performance until your have dependable benchmarks.

Comment: Here is ASM code(this part is enough?):
https://sun9-11.userapi.com/c840724/v840724207/bfbd/kN62Ipo6TZ8.jpg

Comment: If AVX is not so fast, when should it be used? Or should I change the compiler ?

Comment: AVX is not the problem, you're just using it wrong. As usual, save the horizontal part for the end.

Comment: @harold What do you mean :????

Comment: @DesSpigel: it means: do the partial dot products vertically in the loop, and then just do one final horizontal sum at the end.

Answer (score 3):

Simple profiling with basic loops isn't a great idea - it usually just means you are memory bandwidth limited, so the tests end up coming out at about the same speed *(memory is typically slower than the CPU, and that's basically all you are testing here)*.

As others have said, your code example isn't *great*, because you are constantly going across the lanes *(which I assume is just to find the fastest dot product, and not specifically because a sum of all the dot products is the desired result?)*. To be honest, if you really need a fast dot product (for AOS data as presented here), I think I would prefer to replace the VHADDPD with a VADDPD + VPERMILPD *(trading an additional instruction for twice the throughput, and a lower latency)*

```
double dotProduct_3(const double* u, const double* v)   
{  
    __m256d dp = _mm256_mul_pd(_mm256_load_pd(u), _mm256_load_pd(v));
    __m128d a = _mm256_extractf128_pd(dp, 0);
    __m128d b = _mm256_extractf128_pd(dp, 1);
    __m128d c = _mm_add_pd(a, b);
    __m128d yy = _mm_unpackhi_pd(c, c);
    __m128d dotproduct  = _mm_add_pd(c, yy);
    return _mm_cvtsd_f64(dotproduct);
}
```

asm:

```
dotProduct_3(double const*, double const*):
 vmovapd ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
 vmulpd ymm0,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
 vextractf128 xmm1,ymm0,0x1
 vaddpd xmm0,xmm1,xmm0
 vpermilpd xmm1,xmm0,0x3
 vaddpd xmm0,xmm1,xmm0
 vzeroupper 
 ret
```

Generally speaking, if you are using horizontal adds, you're doing it wrong! Whilst a 256bit register may seem ideal for a Vector4d, it's not actually a particularly great representation *(especially if you consider that AVX512 is now available!)*. A very similar question to this came up recently: [For C++ Vector3 utility class implementations, is array faster than struct and class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417117/for-c-vector3-utility-class-implementations-is-array-faster-than-struct-and-c/46420654#46420654)

If you want performance, then structure-of-arrays is the best way to go.

```
struct HybridVec4SOA
{
  __m256d x;
  __m256d y;
  __m256d z;
  __m256d w;
};
__m256d dot(const HybridVec4SOA& a, const HybridVec4SOA& b)
{
  return _mm256_fmadd_pd(a.w, b.w, 
         _mm256_fmadd_pd(a.z, b.z, 
         _mm256_fmadd_pd(a.y, b.y, 
         _mm256_mul_pd(a.x, b.x))));
}
```

asm:

```
dot(HybridVec4SOA const&, HybridVec4SOA const&):
 vmovapd ymm1,YMMWORD PTR [rdi+0x20]
 vmovapd ymm2,YMMWORD PTR [rdi+0x40]
 vmovapd ymm3,YMMWORD PTR [rdi+0x60]
 vmovapd ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rsi]
 vmulpd ymm0,ymm0,YMMWORD PTR [rdi]
 vfmadd231pd ymm0,ymm1,YMMWORD PTR [rsi+0x20]
 vfmadd231pd ymm0,ymm2,YMMWORD PTR [rsi+0x40]
 vfmadd231pd ymm0,ymm3,YMMWORD PTR [rsi+0x60]
 ret
```

If you compare the latencies (and more importantly throughput) of load/mul/fmadd compared to hadd and extract, and then consider that the SOA version is computing 4 dot products at a time (instead of 1), you'll start to understand why it's the way to go...

Comment: Avoiding `vhaddpd` is a win for throughput *and* latency.  There's no tradeoff, `hadd` instructions just suck unless you can use them with 2 different inputs (e.g. as part of a transpose-and-add).  Intel and AMD decode them to 2 shuffle uops that deinterleave odd/even to produce 2 inputs for a vertical add uop.  (Presumably internally using the same shuffle uops as a shufps / shufpd).

Comment: Thanks peter!  I think I left my head unscrewed when I wrote that! Updated the comment.

Answer (score 2):

You add too much overhead with vzeroupper and hadd instructions. Good way to write it, is to do all multiplies in a loop and aggregate the result just once at the end. Imagine you unroll original loop 4 times and use 4 accumulators:

```
for(i=0; i < (1<<30); i+=4) {
  s0 += a[i+0] * b[i+0];
  s1 += a[i+1] * b[i+1];
  s2 += a[i+2] * b[i+2];
  s3 += a[i+3] * b[i+3];
}
return s0+s1+s2+s3;
```

And now just replace unrolled loop with SIMD mul and add (or even FMA intrinsic if available)

Comment: The usual word is "accumulator", not "aggregator".  But yes, exactly.  Thanks for summarizing the comments into an answer.